# работа с методами java

Tags: java

Как данные, которые обработал метод `firstDivid` в частности переменную `divid` передать в качестве входного значения методу `intermCalculate` , то же касается и переменной `i`, которая будет передаваться в следующие методы.

```
   public static void main (String[] args) {
        int divident = 246;
        int divisor = 5;
        int i = 0;            
        String strDiv = Integer.toString(divident); 
        char[] chDiv = strDiv.toCharArray();

        firstDivid(divisor, chDiv, i);
        intermCalculate(divid, divisor);
    }

    public static void firstDivid(int divisor, char[] chDiv, int i){
        StringBuilder strDivid = new StringBuilder();  
        int divid = 1;
        while(divid < divisor){
            strDivid.append(chDiv[i]);
            divid = Integer.parseInt(strDivid.toString());
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void intermCalculate(int divid, int divisor){
        StringBuilder quotToStr = new StringBuilder();
        int intermVal = 1;
        int nextVal = 1;
        int quotient = 1;

        do {
            intermVal = divisor * (quotient-1);
            nextVal = divisor * quotient;
            quotient++;
        } while(intermVal < nextVal && nextVal <= divid);

        quotToStr.append(quotient-2);
        divid = divid - intermVal;
    }
```

---

В метод **formatNewDiv** переменная **divid** после обработки методом **intermCalculate**, уже не передается, точнее передается не обработанная.

```
      public static void firstDivid(int divisor, char[] chDiv, int i){
        StringBuilder strDivid = new StringBuilder();  
        int divid = 1;

        while(divid < divisor){
            strDivid.append(chDiv[i]);
            divid = Integer.parseInt(strDivid.toString());
            i++;
        }

        intermCalculate(divid, divisor);
        formatNewDiv(divid, chDiv, i);
    }
```

Comment: Ну так и вызовите метод `intermCalculate(divid, i)` в чем сложность?

Comment: divid в main не виден, если выношу эту переменную в main, то intermCalculate принимает на вход ее а не после преобразований после метода firstDivid

Comment: А что, метод внутри метода уже запрещено вызывать?

Comment: В следующий раз чтобы дополнить свой вопрос жмите на кнопку [edit]. Пока что я ваше дополнение перенёс в вопрос.

Comment: Самое простое, но не безопасное - сделать переменные `divid` и `i` полями класса (определить сразу после первой `{` где идет заголовок класса), тогда они будут сохранять свое значение в любом месте и методе класса.

Comment: решил переменные помещать в список, и метод потом этот список возвращает

Answer (score 2):

Если подправить метод, то можно получить желанную переменную и передать ее дальше.

```
public static int firstDivid(int divisor, char[] chDiv, int i){
        StringBuilder strDivid = new StringBuilder();  
        int divid = 1;
        while(divid < divisor){
            strDivid.append(chDiv[i]);
            divid = Integer.parseInt(strDivid.toString());
            i++;
        }
        return divid;
}
```

В итоге будет такой вызов:

```
int divid = firstDivid(divisor, chDiv, i);
intermCalculate(divid, divisor);
```

Или так:

```
intermCalculate(firstDivid(divisor, chDiv, i), divisor);
```

Comment: Я думал об этом, но мне надо что-бы значение **i** передавалось дальше в другие методы

Comment: А это еще проще. Пока это простейшая переменная - все изменения останутся в методе. Надо поменять ее на класс Integer (и в main и в firstDivid). Тогда все изменения будут влиять на i объявленную в main. И новые данные можно использовать дальше.

Comment: Откуда информация, что примитивные типы не могут быть полями класса? Это в Java 10 ввели такое ..

Comment: @ pavlofff Я вот тоже не понял, откуда у вас такая информация появилась. Я лишь предложил вариант без вывода в глобальные переменные, а не запрещал этого.